# What does the colloquialisms 'chav' and 'scouse' mean?

Tags: slang, colloquialisms

I have been watching channel 4's Countdown with Jimmy Carr on youtube recently and have heard them mention these two particular colloquialisms/slang and was wondering what exactly they meant?

Comment: Please detail what research you have done, both of these terms should be readily found in a British-English dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

[Chav](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chav) [British] is a derogatory, informal or colloquial term that denotes:

> A young person of a type characterized by brash and loutish behaviour (usually with connotations of a low social status).

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chav) defines chav as an insulting word someone,
usually a young person, whose way of dressing, speaking, and behaving is thought to show their lack of education and low social class.

While [scouse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scouse) is a redundant short form for [scouser](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scouser) [used chiefly in British English], an informal term denoting a person from Liverpool.

Comment: The Cambridge dictionary describes the word as being insulting to use in reference to a person, it doesn’t ‘describe such a person as insulting’